# How to implement faster search in website using Apache Solr?

Tags: performance, apache, solr

I want to use Apache Solr in my website in order to make the search faster.
I need java code to index data from mysql database so that I can perform faster search?
So can anybody please tell me how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with Looking at Solr [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler)
This will enable you to index data from DB to Solr.
You would need to configure Solr to make it faster in performance though and it depends how much and what kind of data you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to use Java code to add data to the index, you should use the [SolrJ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj) client. For the specific case of adding data focus on the [Adding Data to Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#Adding_Data_to_Solr) section. However as @Jayendra pointed out, you can use other means than just Java, like the DataImportHandler, to load data into Solr. Also, please refer to the [Integrating Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/IntegratingSolr) page for a list of additional Solr Client/Language Bindings.

Comment: But can you please tell me how to use dataimporthandler in java code.


Thanks in advance.

Comment: The dataimporthandler is just a rest interface, so you can call it by whatever means you would use to issue http requests in Java.

Comment: I am new to java. Can you please send me a link to an example? Thanks in advance.